# How do I redirect a subdomain blog to a subfolder without .htaccess?

Tags: seo, htaccess, redirects, reverse-proxy, squarespace

I currently have a blog hosted with Squarespace on a subdomain, let's call it `blog.example.com`. I have my storefront hosted separately on `www.example.com`. My blog receives a good amount of traffic, and so I want to merge it with my storefront website.

I have a few issues that are making this process difficult:

1. I can't set up the 301 redirects entirely on Squarespace, because Squarespace doesn't give you access to .htaccess, it doesn't let you redirect all of your pages (some category/archive pages can't be redirected), and I can't do a wildcard redirects either. So I would end up with many pages still live and crawlable on the website.
2. I can't forward the Squarespace `blog.example.com` to [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) and handle the redirects on `www.example.com`, because that would send traffic from the blog's homepage directly to the homepage of `www.example.com`, which is confusing to the user.
3. It might be worth noting that there are pages on the blog I want to redirect to areas on `www.example.com` other than just the subdirectory `www.example.com/blog`; one page should redirect to `www.example.com/about-us`, for example.

I haven't been able to find any resources online that address this specific scenario. I did receive a suggestion to set up a reverse proxy in front of the two domains, but my understanding is that reverse proxies are more for directing traffic from subdomains to ports, not setting up 301 redirects. If I'm wrong, I'd appreciate documentation showing how reverse proxies can be used to redirect hundreds of pages of blog content.

Am I going about this wrong? Is there another solution I'm not thinking of?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to fit a square peg into a round hole... You might be better off just [exporting Squarespace](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206566687-Exporting-your-site) into WordPress and once that's done, move `blog.example.com` to that. Reverse proxies like Nginx can proxy _anything_, but you'll be spending more time setting up and maintaining that then just biting the bullet and upgrading to a less restrictive platform.

Comment: I agree.  If Squarespace can't do redirects, it isn't a host worth using.

Comment: A reverse proxy can, in theory, intercept requests and return 301 redirects.  I guess the how depends on the reverse proxy.  Its late so I'm not fully grasping the nuance of your request  but as a worst case you could write a crude reverse proxy either php and Curl and program it to forward or 301 based on whatever requirement you set.

Comment: @dan 100%. That ought to be an answer.

Comment: @dan, I want to clarify that I'm migrating the content off of Squarespace and moving it to a non-Squarespace provider where my storefront is located, but point well taken. The issue is Squarespace's restrictiveness, and so I'll look into setting up hosting elsewhere with nothing but an .htaccess file with the redirects I need, then repointing the blog subdomain there instead. Do you see any holes in that plan?

Comment: @user3103523 I see. I thought exporting from Squarespace into WordPress might be the easiest option for migration and maintenance given the large number of pages (it allows for .htaccess rewrites too), so that's why I suggested it.  But any host without a website builder should do fine too. Good luck!